# Validating a date before today with VeeValidate

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I'm trying to validate a date of birth field on Vue.js to only allow dates before today, but I am unsure of how to implement Javascript to the [before](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#before) attributes or the  [date_between](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#date-between) attributes

I'm trying to do something along the lines of

```
v-validate="'date_format:DD-MM-YYYY|before:changeDateFormat(new Date(Date.now()))'"
```

where changeDateFormat() is

```
changeDateFormat(dateStr) {
    if (dateStr != null) {
      var date = new Date(dateStr)
      var newDate = ("00"+(date.getDate())).slice(-2)+'-'+("00"+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'+date.getFullYear()
      return newDate
    }
    return ''
```

I'm quite new to Vue.js so I apologise if this is a simple question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use rules expression like object.

> VeeValidate syntax:
>   https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/syntax.html

For example:

```
data: {
    validators: {
        BirthDate: {
            required: true,
            date_format: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            before: this.changeDateFormat(new Date(Date.now()))
        }
    }
},
methods: {
   changeDateFormat(dateStr) {
      if (dateStr != null) {
        var date = new Date(dateStr)
        var newDate = ("00" + (date.getDate())).slice(-2) + '-' + ("00" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +date.getFullYear()
        return newDate
      }
    return ''
   }
},
```

And your directive:

```
v-validate="validators.BirthDate"
```